# mathematica -creating lists and vectors of specific length

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

In Mathematica,

1. How can I create a list of length n
   and fill with zeroes?
2. How can I
   create a vector of length n and fill
   with zeroes?

Comment: In addition to Timo's comment if you think the answer has not been provided in your previous questions please add a comment(s) saying so and why.

Comment: Davorak,

Your answers have been great!  I finally figured out that I can debug mma by first not using the module statement, get it working and then use a module.  The module only was giving me an orange line with no good diagnostics when there was an error in my code.  After removing the module heading and working that way things went much better -good diagnostics etc.  

I had about 20 versions of my module going when I contacted stackoverflow. I needed to get the syntax right.

 This experience has really helped.  I needed to get to the point where I could program quickly.  Thanks. MM

Answer (score 10):

Version 6.0 and up include a new function `ConstantArray` for doing exactly this, and is more efficient than using `Table`:

```
In[2]:= ConstantArray[0,10]
Out[2]= {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0}
```

Documentation here:
http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/ConstantArray.html

Comment: I've been experimenting with lists in Mathematica for a long time, and I think the efficiency of `ConstantArray` over `Table` comes from it being able to pre-calculate and allocate the size of the list.  Since `Table` cannot always do that, it must allocate as it goes.

Answer (score 3):

In Mathematica, there's no distinction between lists and vectors.  You can use the [`Table`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Table.html) function to generate a list of length n:

```
x = Table[0, {n}]
(* If n was 4, x would now be the list {0, 0, 0, 0} *)
```